# set up continuous delivery on docker without wasting bandwidth

Tags: docker, continuous-deployment

I am struggling to run a continuous delivery pipeline with docker. I want to push my apps on a remote VPS running `ubuntu 16.04`
I know I can set up a private docker registery on my VPS but that has one downfall.
I have to literally upload `300 MB` of image to the server. Thats not reasonable for me. I have a limited bandwidth plan.

I was coming with the idea of sending just the `Dockerfile` and all app files and create some `bash` files to `build` an image from the Dockerfile and mount volumes for my app source code and finally running it.

I dont see Docker Private Registry as a reasonable option cause it does not support uploading of Dockerfile and building and running it automatically.

What are the options of automatically deploying my app to vps and running it as a container which are:

1. hassle-free
2. fast and not requiring much bandwidth

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to upload and download Docker images from/to your VPS, the only way is to build them locally, as you said.
Use these images on your project, with volumes if necessary.
Maybe you can use the API to build automatically: https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24/#33-misc (POST /build)

Comment: POST /build takes a zip file and extracts it. It does not let me mount volumes, it does not use a directory, it uses those files as disposable. Not what I was looking for, but thanks.